# Django 'next' not working?

Tags: django, django-comments

Not sure what's wrong here. I'm using the built-in comment form. The form tag is like this:

```
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}?next={% url post post.id %}" method="post">
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="/comments/post/?next=/6/" method="post">
```

Where `/6/` is my Post's post_detail address. However I still end up at this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/comments/posted/?c=4
```

with a

> Thank you for your comment.
>   message

What is going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`next` should be a POST param , not a GET param . 
try add following line into your form

```
 <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url post post.id %}" />
```

and leave the action of the form as `"{% comment_form_target %}"`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. How odd. I copied that code from a tutorial. I guess it's incorrect after all.